# Php exec() with mysql import not working

Tags: php, mysql, windows, shell, command

Im using php exec() to import an uploaded sql file.

```
$cmd = "mysql -h localhost -u forum_user --password=1234 import_forum < C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Temp\import-1452620686.sql"
exec($cmd, $output, $worked);
return $worked;
```

The problem is, its not actually executing anything because nothing is imported to the database. However, if I copy and paste this command into the terminal, it imports just fine.

This seems to be an issue locally on my windows machine because the script works fine in our linux environment.

Also, the $worked variable is returning as 1, which should mean that the command is executed without a problem. But that is not the case.

Is this some kind of a permissions issue? What am I missing?

## Edit 1

The mysql path is set and working properly.

## Edit 2

Actual path is C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Temp\import-1452620686.sql

## Edit 3

$output is an empty array

Comment: have you set msql path to system variable.Because it's did not find mysql command

Comment: Yes, the mysql path is set and working properly.

Comment: Is This mysql -h localhost -u forum_user --password=1234 import_forum < C:\path\to\location.sql run from cmd?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. I've been able to manually execute this command using the command prompt. However, the same command is not executed using php exec().

Comment: Don't know the real path, but `\t` is the tab escape sequence for example, so I'm guessing your Windows path separators are not being escaped.

Comment: Try to run mysql -h localhost -u forum_user --password=1234 import_forum < C:\path\to\location.sql from CMD(command prompt)

Comment: Alex, i've added the real location of the file above.

Comment: which version of xampp, wamp or php are you using?

Comment: xampp 3.2.1 and php 5.5.3

Comment: In the file path, try doubling each of the backslashes eg. `C:\\Users\\path\\to\\file.sql`

Comment: When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir.

Comment: Not in safe mode - I dont think?

Comment: You said the call is returning `1`. On Unix boxen, that indicates an *un*successful execution. Check the contents of `$output`.

Comment: $output ends up being an empty array.

Comment: can you check php error log, i think this has some relation with php.ini settings.

Comment: Last error reported was 3 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't really find a definitive answer to this on stackoverflow so here is all the information I have cobbled together from various sources to get this to finally work, hope it saves somebody some time.
Here is some code to perform a mysql import using php exec and passing a varaiable for the sql import file name. This is running under windows 7 on a WAMP server.
Note the back slashes for the path to mysql (paths will differ for different versions of WAMP) and the forward slashes for the path to the sql import file. Also the parenthesis around the command inside the quotes to get the redirect of the message output.
And finally the redirect of the output "2>&1".

```
    $sqlFile='sqlfile.sql';
    $cmd="(C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.14\bin\mysql --user=USER --password=PASSWORD --host=localhost --database db1 db2 < C:/wamp64/www/site/$sqlFile) 2>&1";
    exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);

    var_dump($return_var);
    echo "return_var is: $return_var" . "\n";
    var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, adding C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql to the beginning of the command resolved my issue.

I dont understand why this is the case, since I added C:\xampp\mysql\bin to the path system variable. When I use the command line manually, I can use the mysql command fine, but PHP appears to need the location..?